# 32u4 not recognized by FLIP

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb, usb, atmega32u4

I recently built a custom PCB with a ATmega32u4. When I plug it in to the USB port it is recognized by windows in the device manager as "ATn32u4DFU". I however can not open a USB port connection to the PCB using FLIP. Is there a reason for this? I attached a schematic if that helps.[image][image]

Comment: Is that a fresh Atmega32U4, without any programming attempts through other interfaces?

Comment: Yes it is a fresh ATmega32u4. All I have done is soldered it to the PCB with all the other components and plugged it into the USB port.

Comment: I don't understand why you see a USB device. It might be another device than your board. It should not work at all. Does the USB device disappear an reappear if you unplug and replug your board?

Comment: Yes, it disappears from device manager when I unplug it and reappears when I plug it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to install a driver for Atmel's DFU bootloader. I followed [these steps](http://flysight.ca/wiki/index.php/Installing_DFU_driver) to fix the issue.

Comment: It only worked because you fixed the hardware with correct crystal before installing the required drivers.

Comment: I switched back to the oscillator and it still functioning.

Comment: So which MCU it is then? Is it a plain Mega32U4 or Mega32U4RC? It absolutely makes a difference what exactly reads on the chip.

Answer (score 0):

It is a surprise it works at all.

The USB connector does not have the required ID resistors so it should be impossible for the computer to detect that anything is connected. But apparently your computer somehow defaults into a mode where it assumes that a standard USB device is plugged in and gives VBUS power out even if nothing is connected. That's unexpected behaviour from the PC.

And apprently the MCU comes with factory programmed DFU bootloader.

But the bootloader requires a properly working 8 or 16 MHz crystal to work which you don't have.

You have a crystal oscillator module, not a crystal, and it does not even have a power supply connected to it, so it is either incorrect part and you need a crystal, or incorrectly connected oscillator which you need to connect properly.

Comment: Is an oscillator not made up of a crystal resonator and an Inverter? I believe I am just utilizing the resonator and not the inverter resulting in the same operation. I will connect an oscilloscope to be sure.

Comment: That part number or schematic symbol are not for a crystal resonator. The part number and schematic symbol are for an integrated crystal oscillator module. The pins for the crystal are not available for connection in an oscillator module. Even if they were, you could not use it, because they are connected to the internal oscillator circuitry already.

Comment: Atmega32U4 has internal pulls for the USB for speed negotiations and it does come with a "feature rich" bootloader, but the bootloader section in the datasheet doesn't do a great job at describing it. Or maybe it's just me.

Comment: @Ralph Based on your comment, I suppose you think I was talking about the pull-ups on data pins? I was not, I was talking about ID resistors you need on the USB-C connector pins to detect device type, and these are left unconnected.

Comment: Right, my mistake, I failed to notice it's an USB C connector.

Comment: I desoldered the crystal oscillator module and replaced it with a 16mhz crystal resonator to two of the pads. The same result has occurred. I don't think the crystal oscillator was the issue.

Comment: @matthewchoe It certainly was an issue, because DFU requires an external crystal and won't work without one. Even if it might boot with RC oscillator (the 32U4RC does) the DFU bootloader will switch to external crystal which needs to be there, properly connected. It may not have been the only issue, and there's still issues left. So it worked because you fixed the crystal before installing required drivers.